# How to put this metric in matrix form?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor

Given the metric

$$ds^{2}=dt^{2}-2 dr dt-r^{2}(d\theta^{2}+\sin^{2}\theta \,d\phi^{2})$$

How to put this metric in matrix form?

I ask this because the metric is obviously not diagonal so what will the component of $g_{rr}$, $g_{tr}$, $g_{rt}$ be?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't missing a $-dr^2$ in that metric?

Comment: boooo! Mostly minus signatures are the worst signatures

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -r^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -r^2\sin^2\theta
\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: But why isn't $g_{rt}=0$ and $g_{tr}=-2$ it would still give the same metric?

Comment: @MrDi: the metric is always symmetric i.e. $g_{\alpha\beta} = g_{\beta\alpha}$

Comment: @MrDi: See [Can a metric in General Relativity, Supergravity, String Theory, etc., be asymmetric?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/162661/)

Answer (score 6):

The diagonal components shouldn't be complicated. For the non-diagonal components, you have to remember that the metric is a symmetric tensor, and therefore $g_{tr}=g_{rt}$.

Expanding the line element:
$$ds^2= g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu= g_{tr}dr dt+ g_{rt} dt dr+\cdots=2g_{rt} dr dt+\cdots$$

So, in your case, $g_{rt}=g_{tr}=-1$.