# Torsion-free and compatible connection for non-symmetric non-degenerate $(0,2)$ tensor field?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, curvature

In order to find a manifestly unique expression for the connection coefficients in terms of a given (possibly non-symmetric) tensor $g_{ab}$ usually *two additional* properties are assumed:

1. Torsion-free: $\Gamma^a_{bc} = \Gamma^a_{(bc)}$ (symmetric in lower indices).
2. Compatibility: $\nabla_a g_{bc} =0$.

Now, by expanding out the equation of the metric compatibility for all three permutations of the indices, subtracting the equations and use of the symmetry of the connection the known Levi-Civita Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^a_{bc}$ in terms of the derivative of the metric are obtained.

In classical GR the metric is symmetric which is needed for the final (known) result of the Levi-Civita Christoffel symbols.

Is it straightforward (to show) to find a corresponding result for [non-symmetric theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonsymmetric_gravitational_theory) with a non-symmetric $(0,2)$ tensor field?

Related: [Can a metric in General Relativity, Supergravity, String Theory, etc., be asymmetric?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/162661)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Given a (possibly non-symmetric) non-degenerate covariant (0,2) [tensor field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_field) $$\mathbb{g}~\in~\Gamma(T^{\ast}M\otimes T^{\ast}M),\tag{1}$$
then a compatible torsionfree tangent-bundle connection $\nabla$ might not exists or be unique. See e.g. the Theorem below.

*Theorem.* Given a non-degenerate [2-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) $$\frac{1}{2}\omega_{ij}\mathrm{d}x^i\wedge\mathrm{d}x^j~=~\omega~\in~\Omega^2(M)~\equiv~\Gamma(\bigwedge\!{}^2T^{\ast}M)\tag{2}$$
on a [paracompact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracompact_space) manifold $M$. Define
$$\frac{1}{3!}\Omega_{ijk}\mathrm{d}x^i\wedge\mathrm{d}x^j\wedge\mathrm{d}x^k~=~\Omega~:=~\mathrm{d}\omega~\in~\Omega^3(M).\tag{3}$$ Then a compatible torsionfree tangent-bundle connection $\nabla$ exists iff $\Omega=0$. In the affirmative case, there are infinitely many such connections.

*Remark.* Such connections are called [Fedosov connections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedosov_manifold), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296519/2451) Phys.SE post.

*Sketched proof of Theorem.* One may show (via [partition of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity)) that there exists a torsionfree connection $\nabla^{(0)}$ on a [paracompact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracompact_space) manifold $M$. We search for a compatible torsionfree connection $\nabla$. The difference in Christoffel symbols $$\Delta\Gamma^k_{ij}~:=~\Gamma^k_{ij}-\Gamma^{(0)k}_{ij}~=~(i\leftrightarrow j)\tag{4}$$
is a $(1,2)$ tensor. If we define a $(0,3)$-tensor
$$\Delta\Gamma_{k,ij}~:=~\omega_{k\ell}\Delta\Gamma^{\ell}_{ij}~=~(i\leftrightarrow j),\tag{5}$$
the compatibility condition
$$\nabla_k\omega_{ij}~\stackrel{?}{=}~0\tag{6}$$
then turn into the tensor equation
$$\begin{align} -\nabla^{(0)}_k\omega_{ij}~\stackrel{?}{=}~&(\nabla_k-\nabla^{(0)}_k)\omega_{ij}\cr
~=~&-\Delta\Gamma^{\ell}_{ki}\omega_{\ell j}-\omega_{i \ell}\Delta\Gamma^{\ell}_{kj}\cr
~=~&\Delta\Gamma_{j,ki}-\Delta\Gamma_{i,kj}.\end{align}\tag{7}$$
If we define a $(0,3)$-tensor
$$ S_{k,ij}~:=~\Delta\Gamma_{k,ij}-\frac{1}{3}\left(\nabla^{(0)}_i\omega_{kj}+\nabla^{(0)}_j\omega_{ki} \right)~=~(i\leftrightarrow j),\tag{8}$$
then eq. (7) becomes
$$\begin{align} \frac{1}{3}\Omega_{ijk}
~=~&\frac{1}{3}\sum_{ijk~{\rm cycl.}}\partial_i\omega_{jk}\cr
~=~&\frac{1}{3}\sum_{ijk~{\rm cycl.}}\nabla^{(0)}_i\omega_{jk}\cr
\stackrel{?}{=}~&S_{i,kj}-S_{j,ki}.\end{align}\tag{9}$$ If $g_{ij}$ is a positive definite diagonal metric (in one coordinate system), then eq. (9) implies
$$ 0~\leq~\Omega_{ijk}(g^{-1})^{i\ell}(g^{-1})^{jm}(g^{-1})^{kn}\Omega_{\ell mn}~\stackrel{?}{=}~0,\tag{10}$$
which in turn implies that $$\Omega~=~0.\tag{11}$$ Conversely if $\Omega=0$, then eq. (9) becomes
$$S_{i,kj}~\stackrel{?}{=}~S_{j,ki},\tag{12} $$
i.e., that
$$S~\stackrel{?}{\in}~{\rm Sym}^3T^{\ast}M\tag{13}$$
is a totally symmetric tensor. But there are infinitely many such totally symmetric tensors $S$, cf. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/295559/2451). So the sought-for connection $\nabla$ is far from unique.
$\Box$

References:

1. B.V. Fedosov, *Deformation Quantization and Index Theory,* Mathematical Topics, Vol. 9, Akademie Verlag, Berlin, 1996; Proposition 2.5.2.